# Zero values in Zabbix items

Tags: zabbix

I am monitoring windows servers with Zabbix and I am using Windows templates. However the network auto-discovery discovers a lot of virtual network interfaces which do have only 0 value all the time.

Is there a way to get rid of them automatically or they don't matter that much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can filter out interfaces using regular expressions. The default template already uses a [global regexp](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/regular_expressions#global_regular_expressions) - you just have to amend it to exclude some more interfaces.